# python is instance() - how to make it worth with classes other than builtins

Tags: python, types, isinstance

Reading documentation for `isinstance()` and looking up examples online, examples only illustrate how to use it with builtin classes like: `str, int, float, long`

I have code where the variable `myObj.location` will either be `None` if it hasn't been set yet, be an empty `str` if the function fails to return a value, or if it succeeds, then the variable will hold an object of type: `geopy.location.Location`

To test what this object holds, I could write code like this:
`isinstance(myObject.location, (type(None), str))`

If `False` then I know it failed to return the `Location` object.  If `True` then it either holds `None` or a `str`.

Is there a way to tell it directly to test if the object is `geopy.location.Location` returning `True` if the test is right?

My code works with the `False` test but I like the readability of being able to say `True` for an object of type `geopy.location.Location` that may or may not have been built for the first time at the moment of the `isinstance` test.

Comment: What makes you think `isinstance` *doesn't* work with non-builtin classes?

Comment: What prevents you from using `isinstance(myObject.location, geopy.location.Location)`? But besides, it would be better if the function raised an exception instead of returning an empty string if it fails to return a meaningful value.

Comment: tried that.  It throws an error.  It does not know that as a type since first instance in my code of that object being created is when the function that populates myObj.location succeeds

Comment: To your other comment - the function is populating a data table.  In this case, it is desirable to not have it raise an exception but to explain that I would have to walk you through a rather lengthy piece of code.  There is a reason why this simple test allows the code to work right.  I was looking to see if there was a way to get around my workaround for better readability.

Comment: `isinstance` works with user-defined classes. If you got an error, you have some other bug. We can't tell what that bug may be.

Comment: I tried feeding in `py.location,Location` and `"py.location.Location"` to `isinstance` but it did not take it.  I see now that there are ways to feed in non-base classes but they have to be built already for the system to recognize them (as per the first answer just posted).  question maybe should be reworded a bit on that point.  This is not a user defined class per se but rather one that comes from the library in use and may get created after the `isinstance` test I need to perform.

Comment: `py.location,Location` has a comma instead of a period, and `py` instead of `geopy`.

Comment: I typed in the original question, but not in the code where I experienced what I was describing.  I have since corrected this in the question.

Answer (score 2):

isinstance() works for user defined classes.

```
>>> class Foo: pass
...
>>> foo = Foo()
>>> isinstance(foo, Foo)
True
>>> isinstance(foo, str)
False
>>>
```